# I can't find the location to select for the target device in VS Code. (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I usually use Android studio for application development with Flutter.
I'm trying to use VSCode, but as the title says, I can't find the selection of the target device I want to run.

For the time being, I selected [Run and Debug] from the icon on the left and executed it, and I was able to run the app on the actual iphone, but I want to run it on macOS.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me where it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the very bottom of your editor, there is a bar, in this bar you should see the name of the currently selected platform, if you click on the platform, you will bring up a menu where you can select the device.

[image: screenshot of vscode]
here is a closeup:
[image: close up of the above image]
In my case you would click on "windows (windows-x64)"

You can also press Ctrl+Shift+P and write `Flutter: select device` to bring up the same menu